# java while loop won't print the text after a the stopping condition

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I just started studying Java and I'm required to use `while` to decided how many *players* can be *goalkeepers* based on their number. The loop is supposed to stop after the user entered `0` and print the counted number of players that can be goalkeepers.

```
public class Q3_201303719 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num; int count=0;

        System.out.println("Enter the players' numbers");
        num = input.nextInt();

        while ((num != 0) && (num < 31) && (num%2==0) || (num%3==0))    
            count++; 

        System.out.println(count+ " players can be goalkeepers.\n");
        // Above line should be printed once the user enter 0, but in my case it won't
        // print and keeps asking the user to enter a number.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code doing? What is the problem? See the [help/on-topic] about homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use a `do-while-loop` as Ubica suggested, then you need to work your way around it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num=2;   // you need to initialize num with a value, that allows you to go inside the while loop at least once
    int count = 0;

    while((num != 0) && (num < 31) && (num % 2 == 0) || (num % 3 == 0)) {
        System.out.println("Enter the players' numbers");  
        num = input.nextInt();   // user input is here inside the loop
        count++;  // your count will count every valid input + the user input that ends the loop
    }
    count--;  // if your user entered 0 to exit the loop, count would have still incremented, so you need do subtract one again
    System.out.println(count + " players can be goalkeepers.\n");
}
```

As I commented in the code, first you initialize `num` with a dummy value, that allows you to enter the loop at least once. Then you listen to the users input and count the loop iterations. But since the loop will execute at least once (even though your user might enter 0 right away to exit the loop) your count would be one higher than the actual number of valid inputs. So you have to subtract that 1 from your count again.

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention: your loop will **not** stop when the user enters `0` because

```
(num % 3 == 0) // is true with num=0
```

so when the user enters `0` the while condition will evaluate like this:

```
while( false && true && true || true ) 
while( false || true )
while( true )
```

Comment: hi, your code worked and gave the exact output as the condition should, however it terminated right after the 3rd input. I also face the same problem when I use for loop. e.g: for(g = 1; g <= 5; g++) supposedly will allow the user to enter 5 times but it stops at the 3rd. There's no error message and I have no idea why it stops.

Comment: maybe you should explain your logic for goalkeepers based on the numbers that user inputs... then we could help you with the actual boolean logic

Comment: @futeenu I am afraid it has something to do with the loop condition. As I mentioned in my edit, that it won't stop the loop even when the user enters `0`, I guess there are a few cases you expect it to continue but it actually stops. If for example you would enter only the number `2`, the loop continues indefinitely. My advice would be to separate the condition "*loop until the user enters 0*" and the condition "*when is a player a goalkeeper, when does the counter increment*"

Comment: Thank you @GameDroids and Ubica , you two have been very helpful and I learnt a lot from this.

Answer (score 2):

From the question it is difficult to understand what it is you are trying to achieve.  However, we can try to help you understand the code as it is written.

The while loop is currently written as:

```
while ((num != 0) && (num < 31) && (num%2==0) || (num%3==0))
```

This could be rewritten as the following and it would not make any difference:

```
while (num != 0 && num < 31 && num%2==0 || num%3==0)
```

The additional parenthesis that you included are not required.

In Java the operator precedence is && before ||.  This means that the && operators will be evaluated first, followed by the ||.  Therefore, the above statement could therefore be rewritten as the following and it would not make any difference:

```
while ((num != 0 && num < 31 && num%2==0) || num%3==0)
```

However, it may make the code a little easier to understand.

So when the code executes the following occurs:

1. The `count` variable is initialised to 0.
2. A value is retrieved and stored in the variable `num`.  Lets say that this value is 10.
3. The while statement is evaluated for the first time:

   ```
   num != 0 is true as 10 != 0.
   num < 31 is true as 10 is less than 31.
   num%2==0 is true as 10 divided by 2 is 5 and leaves a remainder of 0.
   ```

   As these all evaluate to true, the OR part (`num%3==0`) is not evaluated as it is not neccessary.  See short circuit evaluation (http://users.drew.edu/bburd/JavaForDummies4/ShortCircuitEval.pdf).
4. The `count` is incremented to 1.
5. The loop executes again for the second time.  `num` is still 10.

   ```
   num != 0 is true as 10 != 0.
   num < 31 is true as 10 is less than 31.
   num%2==0 is true as 10 divided by 2 is 5 and leaves a remainder of 0.
   ```
6. The `count` is incremented to 2.

And so on... in an infinite loop.

If the variable `num` was instead set to 9. The loop would evaluate as follows:

```
num != 0 is true as 9 != 0.
num < 31 is true as 9 is less than 31.
num%2==0 is false as 9 divided by 2 is 4 and leaves a remainder of 1.
```

Therefore, now the || part is evaluted:

```
num%3==0 is true as 9 divided by 3 is 3 and leaves a remainder of 0.
```

Again, this would result in an infinite loop.

If the variable `num` was instead 0:

```
num != 0 is false
```

As the first `num!=0` is false, the `num<31` and `num%2==0` parts are not evaluated as their results would not make any difference.

The `num%3==0` is then evaluated:

```
num%3==0 is true as 0 divided by 3 leaves a remainder of 0.
```

Again, this would result in an infinite loop.

I hope that this may help to clarify your understanding and allow you to correct the code appropriately.

Comment: good explanation and nice to read, I would give +2 if I could for including the link on short circuit evaluation.

Comment: Woah this made me understand the whole thing a lot better! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

how many players' numbers do you have to input?
you have a while loop that depends on num value, but you never change the num value. that will end up in endless loop...

if you have more players, create a for loop to enter the numbers, store the numbers in an array or an arraylist and if you use the while loop, use it so that it depends on a value that you change inside the loop. otherwise it will loop forever.

```
do{
   System.out.println("Enter the players' numbers");
   num = input.nextInt();
   count++;
}while(num!=0);
```

your code with this should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    int count = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the players' numbers");
        num = input.nextInt();
        count++;
    } while (num != 0);

    System.out.println(count + " players can be goalkeepers.\n");
    // Above line should be printed once the user enter 0, but in my case it
    // won't
    // print and keeps asking the user to enter a number.
}
```

Comment: I can input as much players' number as I want as long as it's not 0, once 0 is entered the count of how many players should be printed. Also, I'm only allowed to use while.

Comment: then the above code should fix your problem

Comment: @futeenu, this is a `while` loop as well, it only allows you to execute the code inside the loop once before checking the condition – which is necessary if you want to ask the user for input

Comment: while the suggested code works perfectly and stops exactly when user input 0, the final count is false. for example if I entered 2,3,5,6,33,0 it should print "3 players can be goalkeepers" but the above code says 6 players.

Comment: @futeenu: you should separate the while condition (loop until the user enters 0) from the condition if you count the player as goalkeeper or not! e.g. `while(num!=0){ if(num%3==0){count++;}}`

Comment: I just gave you an example of the code... you need to implement your condition, because I don't know what is your logic in this :)

Answer (score 0):

The bracketing for the loop should fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need braces surrounding your while loop block. As a general rule, it is best to overuse braces rather than under-use them.

Your code should look like:

```
package q3_201303719;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q3_201303719 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num; int count=0;

        System.out.println("Enter the players' numbers");
        num = input.nextInt();

        while((num != 0) && (num < 31)&& (num%2==0)|| (num%3==0)) {
            count++; 
        }
        // The braces added above are required for the while loop and will keep your program
        // from not outputting your results.

        System.out.println(count+ " players can be goalkeepers.\n");

    }

}
```

Best of luck and happy coding. :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer :)ut when I used the braces it prints the count infinitely. Also I'm sorry if I'm disturbing you but I'm very new to this and it's been stressing me since the deadline is just in few days.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't making sense.

1. 1st : The While loop is not modifying the "num" value, resulting in
   infinite loop if entered.
2. 2nd : What is the code supposed to do? It is really hard to tell from what you show.

I think placing while loop upper could help you, but still code makes no much sense

```
public class Q3_201303719 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int num = 0; int count=0;

       while((num != 0) && (num < 31)&& (num%2==0)|| (num%3==0)) {

          Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter the players' numbers");
          num = input.nextInt();
          count++; 
       }

       System.out.println(count+ " players can be goalkeepers.\n");
       // Above line should be printed once the user enter 0, but in my case it won't
       // print and keeps asking the user to enter a number.
    }    
}
```

Edit : 
This problem occurred because you didn't follow a really simple rule : **think before coding**.
For this exercise you need to think about what your code should be doing, and then write the code for it. Coding is just a language, if you know what you want to write then it is easier. Here you obviously don't really know what you wanna do, and as you are new with development it was likely that you get stucked